# How can I generate images of circles, of varying sizes?

Tags: .net, geometry, transparent

For the task I'm trying to accomplish, I need to generate many images, all consisting of a black circle border on a transparent background, but each a different size (going up in size from 3x3 to, say, 20x20).

Preferably they would be GIFs or PNGs, as these support transparency.

I started building a simple C# Console project for this, but I'm wondering if there's already a tool out there that does this, so I can avoid wasting time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw one 256x256 image of a circle, and scale it down with a batch tool like [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org), [graphicsmagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org), irfan-view, or some-such to all the sizes you need. Little code needed. This assumes you don't need a constantly sized width to the circle outline.

Answer (score 1):

Your strategy sounds good.

Simply create a `Bitmap` of the correct size, create a `Graphics` object using `Graphics.FromImage()`.

Clear the `Graphics` using `Color.Transparent` and draw a black circle with `FillCircle()`.

If you need antialiasing, set smoothing mode to high quality.

Answer (score -1):

I think it would be faster to just make your 18 PNGs in GIMP or some other comparable paint program.

Comment: Until you've changed the colors 10 times and realize that you could have saved time if you had just written a program to do it in the first place.